# correct approach to store in database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing an online website (using Django and Mysql). I have a Tests table and User table.

I have 50 tests within the table and each user completes them at their own pace. 
How do I store the status of the tests in my DB?

One idea that came to my mind is to create an additional column in User table. That column containing testid's separated by comma or any other delimiter.

```
userid | username | testscompleted
1        john       1, 5, 34
2        tom        1, 10, 23, 25
```

Another idea was to create a seperate table to store userid and testid. So, I'll have only 2 columns but thousands of rows (no of tests * no of users) and they will always continue to increase.

```
userid | testid
1        1
1        5
2        1
1        34
2        10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option is vastly preferred... your first solution breaks [normalization rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) by trying to store multiple values in a single field, which will cause you headaches down the road.

The second table will not only be easier to maintain when trying to add or remove values, but will also likely perform better since you'll be able to effectively index those columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are two phrases that should automatically disqualify any database design idea.

- create one table per [anything]
- a column containing [anything] separated by a comma

Separate table, two columns--you're on the right track there.

Comment: but would that cause the table to grow in size. It's a public site and assuming that all the users(say, 10000)  finally complete the tests, there will be  10000*50 rows.

Comment: @John 500,000 rows seems like a lot, but it's still a very small table by database standards.  Say that each row consists of 3 int columns.  That's 12 bytes per row.  12 bytes * 500k rows is only *5.7MB*.

Comment: @John: Tables are supposed to grow when you put useful data in them.